# roscreate-pkg problem

Tags: ros, std-msgs, package, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the tutorial on ros.org and I have a problem with this command:

roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp

'beginner_tutorials' is created and than I got this:

ERROR: dependency [std_msgs] cannot be found

Can anyone help me with this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54122/roscreate-pkg-problem/) by [MoonWalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/4125/moonwalker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try removing std_msgs and then rosmake, if u get the same error for other dependency then there must be problem with path of ros location. You might have not linked ur workspace folder to "/opt/ros/" location. Therefore it is not able to find std_msgs.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1